# Can't update GAE website - another transaction ongoing

Tags: google-app-engine

So I have a website I'm making that I need to be uploaded by Friday. The last version of it that I made I was able to upload to a Google App Engine domain that I created for it no problem. In fact, I was able to upload it multiple times a day. But now I need to update it and it won't let me. It keeps saying I already have a transaction going on, even though I don't. Help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to rollback the update

```
appcfg.py [options] rollback <app-directory>
```

Undoes a partially completed update for the given application. You can use this if an update was interrupted, and the command is reporting that the application cannot be updated due to a lock.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you need to rollback using the appcfg from your google sdk: Here is my full command that I run from my war folder in the comand prompt:

```
"D:\programs\eclipse-kepler\plugins\com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.8.8\appengine-java-sdk-1.8.8\bin\appcfg.cmd" --no_cookies --email=kdimkov@smartinteractive.fr --passin rollback ./
```

The same problem in the googles forums:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1783